# Joomla - 500 - An error has occurred. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: joomla, syntax-error, mariadb

I am using joomla 2.5.28. When I save an article, I always get the following error message:

```
500 - An error has occurred.

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 SQL=UPDATE `mquny_finder_taxonomy_map` SET `link_id`='1093',`node_id`='3' WHERE
```

What can be causing it and how to solve it?

Comment: Let's see the entire query.  The error message implies that something is wrong at the end, possibly an unclosed quote or paren.

Comment: I had searching through the entire joomla script, but unable to find the similar pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and empty Components>Smart Search Indexed Content.

Or manually empty the table mquny_finder_taxonomy_map

I think either will do the trick

Comment: I don't know, but it is also working according to people who were previously experiencing similar problem. Please google "joomla finder_taxonomy_map". I think it is trying to insert new data but unable to do so, because reaching the limit, either memory limit or something else.